# gdb what file am I debugging

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm using gdb's `next n` command, and when I stop,
I usually write `finish` to know in which file I landed:

```
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  klee::Executor::executeAlloc (this=0x5555577dfaf0, ...) at 
/home/oren/GIT/klee/str.klee/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:3218
```

Is there a more elegant way to know **which file am I debugging right now**?

I mean something like:

```
(gdb) next 100
3
3194                   true);
(gdb) whereami
/home/oren/GIT/klee/str.klee/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:3194
```

My current method makes me run everything twice ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [`backtrace` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html#index-backtrace) does what you want:

```
(gdb) backtrace 1
#0  0x00007ffff76ed441 in __pselect (nfds=1, readfds=0x7fffffffcc00, 
    writefds=0x0, exceptfds=0x0, timeout=<optimized out>, 
    sigmask=0x7fffffffcb80) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pselect.c:69
```

Comment: `info frame` and `up` followed by `down` are some of the other ways to get the current frame info.